# SQL Server 2012 Reporting - Users with no knowledge of the datasource (Models are depreciated)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssas

Older versions of SQL had "models" where you could allow users access to data to create ad-hoc reports without having any knowledge of the underlying database.

This feature has been depreciated in SQL2012.

What is the best way to allow users to create ad-hoc reports without knowing about the database?

Answer (score 0):

You can make Use of `REPORT BUILDER` Tool Available in SQL Server Reporting Services. Please refer below links,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/dd220460.aspx

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/35fef0/introduction-of-report-builder-in-sql-server-reporting-servi/

Comment: Isn't report builder just for creating the reports, whereas the old models (and data sources) supplied the data to Report Builder & datasets?